# Typescript: How to define a class that produces callable instances

Tags: typescript

I am currently converting a JS class to TypeScript. The class extends from the NPM module [node-callable-instance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callable-instance) (which makes it a subclass of Function internally). Instances of the class can be called like functions. Short example:

```
import * as CallableInstance from "callable-instance";

class MyClass extends CallableInstance {
  constructor() { super('method'); }
  method(msg) { console.log(msg); }
}

const inst = new MyClass();
inst('test'); // call will be forwarded to "method()"
```

It is a requirement of that special project that these instances are callable, other build-time tooling depends on that.

Is there a way to express that in TypeScript? The code above gives

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'MyClass' has no compatible call signatures.

My first try to workaround this by using a callable interface failed as the class does not implement the call signature...

```
import * as CallableInstance from "callable-instance";

interface MyClassCallable {
  (msg: string): void;
}

class MyClass extends CallableInstance implements MyClassCallable {
  constructor() { super('method'); }
  method(msg: string): void { console.log(msg); }
}

const inst = new MyClass();
inst('test'); // call will be forwarded to "method()"
```

Comment: Do you use any definitions for `callable-instance` ? There don't seem to be an available if I run  `npm install @types/callable-instance`

Comment: Right, there are none, I noticed that already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use interface-class merging and declare an interface with the same name that has the callable signature. The resulting type will have members defined by both the interface and the class:

```
import * as CallableInstance from "callable-instance";

class MyClass extends CallableInstance {
    constructor() { super('method'); }
    method(msg: string): void { console.log(msg); }
}

interface MyClass {
    (name: string): void
}

const inst = new MyClass();
inst('test'); // call will be forwarded to "method()"
```

Comment: This is of course a solid solution, but if the point of `CallableInstance` is to provide ES6 classes that are callable, then the typings it was using when this answer was written were wrong.  The OP shouldn't have had to do anything.  It looks like [the current typings](https://github.com/CGamesPlay/node-callable-instance/blob/master/index.d.ts) should rectify this.