# Typescript decorator interface with lambda. AxiosInstance

Tags: typescript, axios, decorator

I'm facing a problem with typescript about lambda function exposed in index.d.ts file. What I am trying to do is to decorate AxiosInstance in order to cancel pending requests when I want to.

Here is the index.d.ts file, from axios library :

```
export interface AxiosInstance {

  (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise; // How to override this lambda ?
  (url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise; // How to override this lambda ?

  // Omit the rest because ther is no problem with it
}
```

Here is my implementation of AxiosInstance

```
export default class CancelableAxiosInstance implements AxiosInstance {


    private axiosInstance: AxiosInstance;

    constructor(axiosInstance: AxiosInstance){
        this.axiosInstance = axiosInstance;
    }

    // Another function that I want to expose on CancelableAxiosInstance
    cancelRequests() {
       // Omit implementation
    }

    // How do I override (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise; declared in index.d.ts file ?
 }
```

Here is my typescript compiler error shown in IDE :

> TS2420:
>   Class 'CancelableAxiosInstance' incorrectly implements interface 'AxiosInstance'.
>     Type 'CancelableAxiosInstance' provides no match for the signature '(config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise'.

Anybody could help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, in an interface you typically provide the shape of something not the behavior. So if you are trying to override that interface you can just reimplement said method and return something different.

Comment: @MikeTung Actually this inferface is provided by Axios library : https://github.com/axios/axios. What I want to do is to implements this interface but I don't know how to deal with the 2 lambdas described in the index.d.ts file...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: How to define a class that produces callable instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606845/typescript-how-to-define-a-class-that-produces-callable-instances)

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I don't think this is exactly the same issue. Here is my typescript compiler error : TS2420: Class 'CancelableAxiosInstance' incorrectly implements interface 'AxiosInstance'.
  Type 'CancelableAxiosInstance' provides no match for the signature '(config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise<any>'.

Comment: Your error message is different because you tried to declare that the class implements the interface instead of trying to call the class instance directly, but the underlying problem appears the same to me (namely, to define a class with callable instances and get the correct TypeScript type information) and I recommend the solution from the other answer.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen thank you, i'll take a look and implement the given solution when I'll be free!